# why the time in Django rest framework is not correct

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, datetime-format

why when I updated entry in the database the updated time field in the model

```
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

is updated correctly according to timezone in my settings file but when it appeared in the Django rest Framework terminal it is shifting back 3 hours

The following code is for the Model:

```
class hashtag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

the following code is for DRF:

```
last_update = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
class Meta:
    model =  hashtag
    fields = [
        'id',
        'tag',     
        'date_display',
        'last_update',
        'timestamp',
        'updated'

    ]
def get_last_update(self,obj):
    return obj.updated.strftime('%b %d  %I:%M %p')
```

Comment: Share the model code also.

Comment: What timezone are you residing in ?

Comment: @DeepanshParmani shall it differ? anyway `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kuwait'`

Comment: if you are using postgresql you will get the utc timing you might have used USE_TZ=True in settings.py

Comment: @AlbinDavid no I'm using SQLite the default database for django

Comment: check the settings.py USE_TZ value

Comment: @AlbinDavid `USE_TZ = True`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203102/discussion-between-flupper-and-albin-david).

Comment: any help guys ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `SerializerMethodField` you are out of the reach for DRF to properly handle your timezone settings.

So either stick the burden to DRF and use a source to map `updated` to `last_update` :

```
last_update = serializers.DateTimeField(source='updated', format='%b %d  %I:%M %p')
class Meta:
    model =  hashtag
    fields = [
        'id',
        'tag',     
        'date_display',
        'last_update',
        'timestamp',
        'updated'
    ]
```

Or handle the timezone yourself:

```
def get_last_update(self,obj):
    tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()
    return obj.updated.astimezone(tz).strftime('%b %d  %I:%M %p')
```

Comment: @Flupper beware with option #1, just realised you'll need `read_only=True` to avoid making the field writable

Comment: sorry, but why when it was SerializerMethodField it was `readonly` by default and when I change it to DateTimeField I need to add `readonly` option

Comment: i got it @Linovia because readonly is default for SerializerMethodField i checked the code, thanks again man,  you saved to me much time